# a non well formed numeric value encountered, en campo texto,formulario

Tags: php

como puedo filtrar que solo sean numeros. Cojo los datos de un formulario  type text, pero cuando meten 5f, o 5e10 se lo come y me salta el error del titulo,

Se puede cambiar el input por type number, pero sin cambiar esto como sería en el back-end php para controlar esto?

se podría controlar este error por try catch?

Comment: Este tipo de validaciones de formato, se suelen llevar cabo desde el frontend. HTML te da útiles herramientas como el atributo **pattern**, que por medio de expresiones regulares te valida lo que el usuario introduzca en el campo y que te permite hacer la validación de formato antes de llegar al backend.

Comment: gracias, no sabía de  pattern en html, solo en java. Un saludo